# How to show that basis of space of Dirac gamma-matrices is given by following matrices?

Tags: dirac-equation, matrix-elements

How to show that 16 matrices
$$
\mathbf E , \quad \gamma^{\mu}, \quad \gamma^{5} = \frac{i}{4}\gamma^{0}\gamma^{1}\gamma^{2}\gamma^{3}, \quad \eta^{\mu \nu} = -\frac{1}{4}\left(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu} - \gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}\right), \quad \gamma^{5}\gamma^{\mu}  \qquad (.1)
$$
create the basis in space of Dirac matrices, by having
$$
[\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}]_{+} = 2g^{\mu \nu}\mathbf E ?
$$ 
I don't want to calculate each of matrices $(.1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I can see only 12 different nonzero matrices. Perhaps you missed $\gamma^5\gamma^\mu$.

EDIT: There is a proof of linear independence of the 16 matrices, e.g., in Bogoliubov and Shirkov's Introduction to theory of quantized fields. They prove (using trace invariance under cyclic permutations and anticommutation relations) that each of the matrices, except E, has zero trace, assume that a nontrivial linear combination of the matrices vanishes and show (multiplying this linear combination separately by each of the matrices) that this assumption is in contradiction with the trace of each matrix (except E) being zero.